# How to create a signal m(t)?

Tags: fourier-transform, cosine

I have this signal $m(t)=8\sin(9\pi t)\sin(8\pi t)$, my teacher gave as explain $2\sin x \sin y=\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)$. So how to create and get this signal $m(t)=a\cdot\cos(2\pi f_c t)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have converted you mathematical expressions into [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (edit may be pending). Please check I have done so correctly and consider using MathJax in the future.

Comment: Please check your assignment. The way you describe it seems wrong: that can't be done.